# How can I buy Bitcoins / Litecoins with Paypal or a credit card?

Tags: bitcoin, paypal

I've tried looking for a simple solution for buying Bitcoins or litecoins with Paypal or a credit card but it seems that all of the places around are accepting only wire transfers. Is this logical ? How come no one credible allows you to buy Bitcoin without waiting 10 days for a wire transfer ?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Unfortunately, this question does not seem to be within scope, and should instead be [over at the BitCoin Q&A](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/). *[Not to mention that it's a pretty active question.](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/how-can-i-buy-bitcoin-via-a-credit-card-or-paypal)*

Comment: There are very few solutions to purchase Bitcoins with PayPal.  There are even fewer solutions that allow you to purchase Litecoin with PayPal.  One solution actually is Ebay.  The reason nobody credible takes PayPal is because PayPal will keep you from your funds given certain situations, some directly connected to Bitcoins and Litecoins, I suggest you consider the credible solutions that deal with wire transfers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've actually already talked about this on StackExchange but here we go again :)
There's a barrier when you try to purchase Bitcoins, Litecoins or any other crypto currency for that matter with a form of payment that allows chargeback (i.e. Paypal or a credit card). Take a look at Paypal's TOS section 3.7.

You can still use [VirWox](http://virrwox.com) to buy Second Life Lindens (SLL) with Paypal or a credit card and then trade these Lindens to BTC. It will cost you though, there are fees of around %6-8 since you are using 2 different exchanges. The full process is shown [step by step here](http://99bitcoins.com/buying-bitcoins-with-paypal-a-practical-guide/).

If you don't want to pay the fees and just want to make a profit out of the currency's volatility you can trade CDFs (Contract for Difference) - these are easily bought with Paypal or a credit card and are available for Bitcoin and Litecoin as well. Keep in mind that when you trade CFDs you're putting your capital at risk and that it's usually more suitable for experienced trader.

One final option is actually buying the coins on Ebay but there will be a premium price there since the sellers have to protect themselves from chargebacks.